# How to change softmax activation function layer of InceptionV3 into linear activation function layer?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have imported InceptionV3 but need to change only softmax layer into linear activation function layer.
I have implemented this much
from tensorflow.keras.applications import InceptionV3

```
pre_model = InceptionV3(input_shape = (224, 224, 3), 
                                include_top = False, 
                                weights = 'imagenet')

# Make all the layers in the pre-model non-trainable
for layer in pre_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False
```

What to do next?

```
layers.Dense  (1, activation='linear')
```

Where to place above code inorder to change `activation='softmax'` into `activation='linear'` in this architecture?
(I don't need softmax I need linear activation function)
I am training a model which predicts continuous value from a given image.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this,

```
model = Sequential([ pre_model, Dense(1, activation="linear") ])
```

Look up transfer learning.

Ref:

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning